# Localization of PyGObject GUI using Gettext

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygobject

I have directory, which is called **locale** and subdirectories with languages (*ru*, *ua*, *de* etc.)

My Python script is translated:

```
from libs.gettext_windows import gettext_windows

scriptdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))  # directory with this script
# translating strings in _()
lang = gettext_windows.get_language()
translation = gettext.translation("vk_stats", localedir="{}/locale".format(scriptdir), languages=lang)
_ = translation.gettext
```

How I can localize my GUI *(in development)*?

[vk_stats.ui](http://pastebin.com/yiuZ8g0v)

I prefer to use **Glade**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540744/439494

The procedure is very well explained there.

Also you might need to do this also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8377533/439494